# How to determine how many years (D/M/Y) left from the Birthday to a certain age in age calculator?

Tags: javascript, html-table, calculator

What should I need to change to determine how many years (D/M/Y) left from the Birthday to a certain age? i.e my birthday is 01.01.1990 and and today my age is 27 Years, 5 month.... and I will 50 years old in 2040.

I want to know How many years left (DD/M/Y) from today to become 50 years old? 
Another thing is Concern title should be just above the result not left side of the result.
Code below for this script and and two picture regarding this..

[image: 1st Picture (the Original)]

[image: 2nd Picture (what I expect)]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>


function wr_document()
{
var w=new Date();
var s_d=w.getDate();
var s_m=w.getMonth()+1;
var s_y=w.getFullYear();


document.cir.len11.value=s_d;
document.cir.len12.value=s_m;
document.cir.len13.value=s_y;
}

function isNum(arg)
{
var args = arg;
if (args == "" || args == null || args.length == 0)
{
return false;
}
args = args.toString();
for (var i = 0; i<args.length; i++)
{
if ((args.substring(i,i+1) < "0" || args.substring(i, i+1) > "9") && args.substring(i, i+1) != ".")
{
return false;
}
}
return true;
}
function checkday(aa)
{
var val = aa.value;
var valc = val.substring(0,1);
if(val.length>0 && val.length<3)
{
if(!isNum(val) || val == 0)
{
aa.value="";
}
else if( val < 1 || val > 31)
{
aa.value=valc;
}
}
else if(val.length>2)
{
val = val.substring(0, 2);
aa.value=val;
}
}
function checkmon(aa)
{
var val = aa.value;
var valc = val.substring(0,1);
if(val.length>0 && val.length<3)
{
if(!isNum(val) || val == 0)
{
aa.value="";
}
else if(val < 1 || val > 12)
{
aa.value=valc;
}
}
else if(val.length>2)
{
val = val.substring(0, 2);
aa.value=val;
}
}
function checkyear(aa)
{
var val = aa.value;
var valc = val.substring(0,(val.length-1));
if(val.length>0 && val.length<7)
{
if(!isNum(val) || val == 0)
{
aa.value=valc;
}
else if(val < 1 || val>275759)
{
aa.value="";
}
}
else if(val.length>4)
{
aa.value=valc;
}
}
function checkleapyear(datea)
{
if(datea.getYear()%4 == 0)
{
if(datea.getYear()% 10 != 0)
{
return true;
}
else
{
if(datea.getYear()% 400 == 0)
return true;
else
return false;
}
}
return false;
}
function DaysInMonth(Y, M) {
with (new Date(Y, M, 1, 12)) {
setDate(0);
return getDate();
}
}
function datediff(date1, date2) {
var y1 = date1.getFullYear(), m1 = date1.getMonth(), d1 = date1.getDate(),
y2 = date2.getFullYear(), m2 = date2.getMonth(), d2 = date2.getDate();
if (d1 < d2) {
m1--;
d1 += DaysInMonth(y2, m2);
}
if (m1 < m2) {
y1--;
m1 += 12;
}
return [y1 - y2, m1 - m2, d1 - d2];
}
function calage()
{
var curday = document.cir.len11.value;
var curmon = document.cir.len12.value;
var curyear = document.cir.len13.value;
var calday = document.cir.len21.value;
var calmon = document.cir.len22.value;
var calyear = document.cir.len23.value;
if(curday == "" || curmon=="" || curyear=="" || calday=="" || calmon=="" || calyear=="")
{
alert("Please fill all the values and click 'Go'");
}
else if(curday == calday && curmon==calmon && curyear==calyear)
{
alert("Today your birthday & Your age is 0 years old")
}
else
{
var curd = new Date(curyear,curmon-1,curday);
var cald = new Date(calyear,calmon-1,calday);
var diff = Date.UTC(curyear,curmon,curday,0,0,0)
- Date.UTC(calyear,calmon,calday,0,0,0);
var dife = datediff(curd,cald);
document.cir.val.value=dife[0]+" years, "+dife[1]+" months, and "+dife[2]+" days";
var secleft = diff/1000/60;
document.cir.val3.value=secleft+" minutes since your birth";
var hrsleft = secleft/60;
document.cir.val2.value=hrsleft+" hours since your birth";
var daysleft = hrsleft/24;
document.cir.val1.value=daysleft+" days since your birth";
//alert(""+parseInt(calyear)+"--"+dife[0]+"--"+1);
var as = parseInt(calyear)+dife[0]+1;
var diff = Date.UTC(as,calmon,calday,0,0,0)
- Date.UTC(curyear,curmon,curday,0,0,0);
var datee = diff/1000/60/60/24;
document.cir.val4.value=datee+" days left for your next birthday";
}
}
function color(test)
{
for(var j=7; j<12; j++)
{
var myI=document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(j);
//myI.setAttribute("style",ch);
myI.style.backgroundColor=test;
}
}
function color1(test)
{
var myI=document.getElementsByTagName("table").item(0);
//myI.setAttribute("style",ch);
myI.style.backgroundColor=test;
}

</script>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">
.cal-container {
 width: 540px;
margin: 10px auto 0; 
}
#age-calculator {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DDDDDD;
    border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.calc {
    border-color: #AAAAAA #999999 #929292 #AAAAAA;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 2px 2px 1px;
    padding: 2px 30px 3px;
    height: 27px;
}
.calc:active {
    border-color: #AAAAAA #999999 #929292 #AAAAAA;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

</style>


<title>Age calculator</title>
</head>
<body onLoad="wr_document()">
<div class="cal-container">
<div id="calculator-container">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<h1 style="padding-top: 10px;">Age Calculator</h1>
<div class="descalign">
<span>Calculate your age in days, years, minutes, seconds. Know how many days are left for your next birthday.</span><br/><br/>
</div>
<div id="age-calculator">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<table class="result" width="100%" height="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<form name="cir">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<br>
Today's  Date is:
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="2">
Date -
<input class="innerc resform" type="text" value="" onkeyup="checkday(this)" size="2" name="len11">
Month -
<input class="innerc resform" type="text" value="" onkeyup="checkmon(this)" size="2" name="len12">
Year -
<input class="innerc resform" type="text" value="" onkeyup="checkyear(this)" size="4" name="len13">
<br>
<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> Enter Your Date of Birth : </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="2">
Date -
<input class="innerc resform" type="text" onkeyup="checkday(this)" size="2" name="len21">
Month -
<input class="innerc resform" type="text" onkeyup="checkmon(this)" size="2" name="len22">
Year -
<input class="innerc resform" type="text" onkeyup="checkyear(this)" size="4" name="len23">
<br>
<br>
<input class="calc" type="button" onclick="calage()" value=" Go " name="but">
<br>
<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="form" width="30%" align="center">
<b> </b>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<b> Your Age is </b>
</td>
<td>
<input class="resform" type="text" readonly="" size="36" name="val">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<b> Your Age in Days </b>
</td>
<td>
<input class="resform" type="text" readonly="" size="36" name="val1">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<b> Your Age in Hours </b>
</td>
<td>
<input class="resform" type="text" readonly="" size="36" name="val2">
(Approximate)
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="form">
<b> Your Age in Minutes </b>
</td>
<td>
<input class="resform" type="text" readonly="" size="36" name="val3">
(Approximate)
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<b> Your Next Birthday</b>
</td>
<td>
<input class="innerc resform" type="text" readonly="" size="36" name="val4">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" colspan="2"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways to achieve what you're asking. 
For the formatting, you could define CSS rules for the table to be something like:
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;

For the time until the 50th birthday, you could add 50 years in ms to the birth date and calculate accordingly, however you might need to be aware of the following in your calculations:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem